# Local Node Packages - importing and updating in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package

I am building a web crawler and a web site, and want to split out some functionality and Mongoose models into packages, so they can be easily shared across projects.

Within the package.json file for my site project, I have:

```
{
  "name"         : "Website",
  "version"      : "0.0.3",
  "private"      : true,
  "dependencies" : {
    "ian-mongoose": "file:../readikus_modules/ian-mongoose",
    "ian-parse-page": "file:../readikus_modules/ian-parse-page"
  }
}
```

The paths are valid, and I have (seemingly randomly) been able to get the npm install to install my packages, however, if I update the code for one of the modules, and do an npm install/npm update, the changes do not seem to flow across.

Any thoughts? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You may wish to try npm link (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) rather than using file uris. Linking allows rapid development of new modules - you can develop your ian-mongoose module and have changes apply instantly to whatever projects depend upon it.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I will give that a try!